# React native app that can control other app

Tags: android, react-native

I want to make an app that can control access to all installed apps. Is that possible using react native? I want to deploy to android device.

the idea is:
some admin user can define apps that are permanently accessible
all apps, that are not defined as permanently accessible are accessible for only x minutes total per day
i mean, not EACH app x minutes, but ALL apps together x minutes
like a control for children
that they can not play hp unlimited but still have access to the relevant apps

is it possible?